# load pathForResource from a text field?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, sdk

Hey so i am trying to give my music player a path from which it will find the music file to play but i have one question. Is it possiable to read the pathForResource from a text field instead?

I have a table view, whena row is clicked a new view pops up where the sound will be played.

#### Regular:

```
NSString * pathToMusicFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Katy" ofType:@"mp3"];
```

#### I Want

```
NSString * pathToMusicFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:myTextField.text ofType:@"mp3"];
```

Can i give the resouce name via a text field? I tried the above but it will not read it.

Comment: Why are you making the user enter a pathname into an iPhone application?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that myTextField.text is actually the string that you entered? Try doing a simple NSLog.

If your "regular" code works, but not your "I Want" code, then it's 99% likely that myTextField.text simply isn't what you think it is.

(As a side question, does your "regular" code work?)